# PCA Biplot : A way to hide vectors to see all data points clearly

Tags: r

I am trying to do PCA with R.

My Data has 10,000 columns and 90 rows
I used the prcomp function to do PCA.
Trying to prepare a biplot with the prcomp results, I ran into the problem that the 10,000 plotted vectors cover my datapoints. Is there any option for the biplot to hide the vectors' representation?

OR

I can use `plot` to get the PCA results. But I am not sure how to label these points according to my datapoints, which are numbered 1 to 90.

```
Sample<-read.table(file.choose(),header=F,sep="\t")

Sample.scaled<-data.frame(apply(Sample_2XY,2,scale))

Sample_scaled.2<-data.frame(t(na.omit(t(Sample_2XY.scaled))))

pca.Sample<-prcomp(Sample_2XY.scaled.2,retx=TRUE)

pdf("Sample_plot.pdf")

plot(pca.Sample$x)

dev.off()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you do a `help(prcomp)` or `?prcomp`, the help file tells us all the things contained in the `prcomp()` object returned by the function.  We just need to pick which things we want to plot and do it with some function that gives us more control than `biplot()`.

A more general trick for cases when the help file doesn't clarify things is to do a `str()` on the prcomp object (in your case pca.Sample) to see all its parts and find what we want ( `str()` compactly displays the internal structure of an R object. )

Here is an example with some of R's sample data:

```
# do a pca of arrests in different states
p<-prcomp(USArrests, scale = TRUE)
```

`str(p)` gives me something ugly and too long to include, but I can see that p$x has the states as rownames and their locations on the principal components as columns. Armed with this, we can plot it any way we want, such as with `plot()` and `text()` (for labels):

```
# plot and add labels
plot(p$x[,1],p$x[,2])
text(p$x[,1],p$x[,2],labels=rownames(p$x))
```

If we are making a scatterplot with many observations, the labels may not be readable. We therefore might want to only label more extreme values, which we can identify with `quantile()`:

```
#make a new dataframe with the info from p we want to plot
df <- data.frame(PC1=p$x[,1],PC2=p$x[,2],labels=rownames(p$x))

#make sure labels are not factors, so we can easily reassign them
df$labels <- as.character(df$labels)

# use quantile() to identify which ones are within 25-75 percentile on both
# PC and blank their labels out
df[ df$PC1 > quantile(df$PC1)["25%"] & 
    df$PC1 < quantile(df$PC1)["75%"] &
    df$PC2 > quantile(df$PC2)["25%"] &
    df$PC2 < quantile(df$PC2)["75%"],]$labels <- ""

# plot
plot(df$PC1,df$PC2)
text(df$PC1,df$PC2,labels=df$labels)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But in my case rownames(pca.Sample$x) gives result as NULL. where as rownames(Sample) gives numbers from 1 to 90. Is there is way I can get the same row numbers to pca.Sample$x

Comment: Can you str(pca.Sample) and add the result to your question? Are you attempting to reduce the 90 dimensions to a smaller number in which 10,000 observations occur or reduce the 10,000 dimensions to a smaller number in which 90 observations occur?

Comment: I donot understand your question much. I am very new to R. However here is the result of str(pca.Sample) which you had asked for.To be more precise I have 90 rows and 9912 columns.`str(pca.Sample)List of 5
 $ sdev    : num [1:90] 87.21 38.37 12.26 8.79 6.2 ...
 $ rotation: num [1:9912, 1:90] 0.01135 -0.0108 -0.00551 -0.00868 -0.0099 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:9912] "V1" "V2" "V3" "V4" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:90] "PC1" "PC2" "PC3" "PC4" ...
 $ center  : Named num [1:9912] 4.56e-17 4.16e-18 -9.49e-17 -6.03e-17 5.09e-17 ...
`

Comment: Rest of the lines here in this comment                               `$ scale   : logi FALSE
 $ x       : num [1:90, 1:90] -78.8 88.2 -61.6 87.3 -62.1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr [1:90] "PC1" "PC2" "PC3" "PC4" ...
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "prcomp"
`

Comment: I meant edit your question and add the str() result there where you have no space limit.  :-)  The way you are doing the PCA, you seeing how your 90 rows could be represented as a smaller number of rows (principal components), while maintaining the 9912 columns.  Is that what you want?  Looks like you don't have rownames in pca.Sample$x, but names stay in order, so you could use rownames(p$rotation)

Comment: And by rownames(p$rotation) I meant rownames(pca.Sample$rotation) . Sorry I was switching between my sample and your code,

Comment: yes. My aim is I need to see how my 90 rows behave in all of these 9912 columns and finally see 90 data points labeled with their corresponding numbers  in the plot.  rownames((pca.Sample$rotation) gives me the names of 9912 columns. I used text(pca.Sample$x[,1],pca.Sample$x[,2],labels=rownames(Sample))
 and got the rows numbered 1 to 90 marked on my data points on the figure. I hope the order in which they are labeled is correct

Comment: That may work, but it is riskier code to pull the labels from a different object instead of from the prncomp object, i.e. rownames(pca.Sample$rotation).  If your na.omit caused you to lose a variable between Sample and pca.Sample, you would have errors. (p.s. don't forget to accept answers to your questions to indicate your problem is solved and give points to answerer :-)  )

Comment: I had some columns removed when I did na.omit, but as far as I know didnot loose any rows(1:90) whcih I need to label. ( Sorry for being late in accepting the answers and giving points) Thanks a lot for the help!!