# Plotting PCA : way to label data points

Tags: r

I can use Plot function. Could use plot to get the pca results. But not sure how to label these points according to my datapoints which are `rownames(Sample)` numbered 1 to 90

```
Sample<-read.table(file.choose(),header=F,sep="\t")
Sample.scaled<-data.frame(apply(Sample_2XY,2,scale))
Sample_scaled.2<-data.frame(t(na.omit(t(Sample_2XY.scaled))))

pca.Sample<-prcomp(Sample_2XY.scaled.2,retx=TRUE)

pdf("Sample_plot.pdf")
plot(pca.Sample$x)
dev.off()
```

Comment: @Julius : Thanks for the proper formatting

Comment: possible duplicate of [PCA Biplot : A way to hide vectors to see all data points clearly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13367880/pca-biplot-a-way-to-hide-vectors-to-see-all-data-points-clearly)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simple way of doing it, with plotting the first two components:

```
plot( pca.Sample$x[,1], pca.Sample$x[,2] )
text( pca.Sample$x[,1], pca.Sample$x[,2], rownames( Sample ), pos= 3 )
```

By the way, you can use your regular device to see the plots on the go, and then copy the contents of that device to PDF:

```
dev.copy2pdf( file= "something.pdf" )
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I tried the above code. But my plot still looked the same without any labels.                                          `rownames(pca.Sample$x)
NULL`   which means there are no rownames, wheres as rownames(Sample)  has rownames 1 to 90.

Comment: Just use rownames(Sample). The order of the data is the same in both. You may want to use pch="" in your plot file so the labels do not overprint the symbols or use the pos= argument in text() to place below, left, above, or right of the symbol.